# Error "$T5??' does not have a member named 'Generator'" in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm trying to use **allContactedBodies()** in Swift but I keep getting the error `'$T5??' does not have a member named 'Generator'`:

> class Sense : SKNode {
>       override init() {
>           super.init()
>       }
>
> ```
> required init(coder: NSCoder) {
>     fatalError("NSCoding not supported")
> }
>
> init(size: CGSize) {
>     // Initialize shape
>     super.init()
>
>     // Physic Properties
>     self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: size)
>     self.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
>     self.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.Vision.toRaw()
>     self.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
>     self.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = ColliderType.Wall.toRaw()
>     self.hidden = true
> }
>
> func contact() -> Bool {
>     for body : AnyObject in self.physicsBody?.allContactedBodies() { // Here is the error
>         return true
>     }
>     return false
> } }
> ```

How can I fix it so I can use allContactedBodies()?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`self.physicsBody?.allContactedBodies()` returns an optional so this makes the whole expression optional due to optional chaining. You can either use the nil coalescing operator to use an empty array in the case `self.physicsBody` is nil

```
for body: AnyObject in self.physicsBody?.allContactedBodies() ?? [] {
    return true
}
return false
```

or use "if let" unwrapping to get at the physics body in the case its there.

```
if let physicsBody = self.physicsBody {
    for body : AnyObject in physicsBody.allContactedBodies() {
        return true
    }
    return false
} else {
    return false
}
```